# Fibonacci using Recursion Starting with two Arbitrary Numbers Given by User at CLI in Java

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, command-line-interface, sequence

Lately, I started to test something that's been on my mind for a while now. The Fibonacci sequence scheme has several methods to get solved, but in this instance I'm trying to do something slightly different. I'm trying to use recursion with numbers given by the user at the CLI. This is what I got so far. I'm including an iterative version that seems to work for comparison purposes.

Numbers given by user at CLI: 4 and 6. The number **9** is the **n** here.

Iterative:

```
1: ite: 6 
2: ite: 10
3: ite: 16
4: ite: 26
5: ite: 42
6: ite: 68
7: ite: 110
8: ite: 178
9: ite: 288
```

Recursive:

```
1: rec: 16
2: rec: 33
3: rec: 59
4: rec: 102
5: rec: 171
6: rec: 283
7: rec: 464
8: rec: 757
9: rec: 1231
```

Method for recursive version:
here **num0** and **num1** are the variables that hold the values given at CLI.

```
public int Recursive(int n) {
    //....
        int a = num0;
        int b = num1;
        if(n < 0)
        {
          return n;
        }else{
           int c = a+b;
           a = b;
           b = c;
          return Recursive(n-1)+Recursive(n-2)+c;     
        }
    }
```

Any thoughts or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: not sure if this is fib.. first: why are you letting the user input 2 numbers? `fn` is defined by `fn-1` + `fn-2` ... also.. in your 'recursive' function, you want more like `n <= 1` otherwise you will always return a negative number...?

Comment: Btw, the fibonacci #s are: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21...

Comment: That's the main reason I posted this question on Stackoverflow because I'm not clear how to work with two arbitrary inputs given by the user at CLI using specifically the fibonacci Recursive method.

Comment: @FullArray two inputs doesnt make sense.. you want the `fibonacci` number at `index n`, which as said above is defined by the sum of the previous two fib numbers at `index n-1` and `index n-2`

Comment: @Aderis gave the answer. Of course, you will need to adapt it to your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use two arbitrary numbers as the starting points, you just need to take the simple fibonacci recursive version and tweak the base case slightly. Instead of just returning `n` when `n` is `0` or `1`, we check for specific values of `n` and return the appropriate starting values. Remember, the base case(s) are just the answers to the problems that cannot be broken down anymore by recursion.

```
public int recurse(int first, int second, int n)
{
    switch (n)
    {
        case 0:  return first;
        case 1:  return second;
        default: return recurse(first, second, n - 1) + recurse(first, second, n - 2);
    }
}
```

To use the above function, you can do something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int first =  // get from user (first number in the sequence)
    int second = // get from user (second number in the sequence)
    int n =      // get from user (which number in the sequence to compute)
    int answer = recurse(first, second, n);

    System.out.println(answer);
}
```

Note that since first and second are passed in every function call and never change, they could be stored as instance fields or globals to avoid passing them every time the function is called.

Comment: This is the answer. Mind blowing.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the helper function.

```
public int Recursive(int n) {
    // ....
    int a = 4;
    int b = 6;
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
    n--;
    return RecursiveFib(a, b, n);
}

private int RecursiveFib(int a, int b, int n) {
    if (n < 1) {
        return b;
    } else {
        System.out.println(a + b);
        int tmp = a;
        a = b;
        b += tmp;
        n--;
        return RecursiveFib(a, b, n);
    }
}
```

Since your starting numbers can be arbitrary, it is different to apply the fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) logic unless you store all your numbers.

Comment: i thought for the sequence to be a fibonacci sequence, the starting numbers have to sequential fib numbers themselves... ? ie, `4` and `6` are not fibonacci numbers nor will they give you any

Comment: This seems to be a twist on the traditional fibonacci numbers. Instead of starting with `0, 1` you can start with any two numbers and apply the same concept to get the next number by adding the last two numbers. But because of the starting point is not 0 and 1, you cannot go backwards like we do with traditional fibonacci numbers.

Comment: ah well that's all fine and good but then it is no longer the fibonacci sequence! :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need temp variables with recursion. The arguments for each call (in this case n) is your changing value for each recursive call. So you just operate on it. If you are at the base case (n = 2, or n = 1, or n = 0) you just give it back. Otherwise you call fibonacci again on a smaller value.

```
int fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return n;
    }


    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use recursion with two arbitrary values given by the user at CLI. The method you posted I got it under my belt, but I'm trying it make recursion more "Dynamic" by allowing the user to begin the Fibonacci sequence at any two numbers.

Comment: As in, for example, beginning the sequence at the 6th and 7th Fibonacci #, and then printing the series from there?

Comment: For example, the Fibonacci sequence starts normally with 1,1,...and so on. In my question, I'm trying to start the "sequence" with any two numbers given by the user at CLI, say e.g. 5 and 6. So instead of starting traditionally at 1,1,...etc, I'm starting with 5,6 and build up from these numbers. I was able to do it with the iterative method but recursion is a different beast. Recursion is what I'm aiming for.

Answer (score -2):

someone else already posted the `recursive` version (without caching) so here's the `iterative`:

```
def fib_iter(n):
    a, b = 0, 1 # or: a, b = 1, 1

    i = 0
    while i < n:
        c = a + b
        a = b
        b = c

        i+=1

    return c

print fib_iter(10)
```

*EDIT*

based on the comments:

you cant start the sequence anywhere without first calculating the values and then storing them away so that in the future, you can look them up:

```
def fib(n, table):
    if n in table:
        return table[n]
    if n <= 1:
        return n

    table[n] = fib(n - 1, table) + fib(n - 2, table)

    return table[n]


cache = {}

f_goal = 1000
f = 1

while f < f_goal:
    print(fib(f, cache))
    f += 1
```

Comment: I got the iterative method @mad.meesh. The tricky part comes with the recursion method and two arbitrary values given by the user at CLI.